# CakePHP update two table in same time

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Hi I'm working on a project for a nightclub system. Our client wants to have an electronic sign in page at events, where he can sign in patrons automatically into the database. At the same time, he wants to be able to identify which patrons attended which events. In our database we've accommodated this by using a "Guestlist" table that joins an event ID (event) with a patron ID.

My interpretations of event-flow at this moment is:

- A patron comes to the counter and gives info to be enterred into database.
- Info is submitted and goes into the Patron Table, generating a patron ID.
- The Guest list table for said event then gets the patron ID and the event ID of the event, both referenced from respective tables, and joins the tables.
- from the guest list table the user can view the events ID and patron info that was submitted.

I'm not sure whether I've missed a step or if our database is incomplete/incorrect but we have no idea how to procceed with this in cakePHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are happy to help you solve specific coding questions as you develop your application, but broad conceptual questions are off-topic for this site. You may wish to browse the FAQ at http://programmers.stackexchange.com to determine whether it is a better fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are related and your models are set up correctly you can use the [`saveAssociated`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Your models should be set up with the relevant relationships.  Normally it would be a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship, but as you want to use the GuestList data for checkin a [`hasManyThrough`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) would be better

This is very roughed out to give a starting point, please.. please read the docs I've linked to for a more complete example of the solution

```
<?php
class Patron extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array('GuestList');
}

class GuestList extends AppModel 
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Patron',
        'Event'
    );
}

class Event extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array('GuestList')
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing , i m still trying to figure out in the model. still can't get it to work yet.